# How to Collapse already opened ExpansionPanel after clicking on another ExpansionPanel in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I read the questions that were asked in this regard, but I did not get an answer or I made a mistake somewhere
According to the code I have, when clicking on each panel, the panels that were already open are not closed. And this is because I use one variable for all of them
How can this be solved?

```
bool isExpanded = false;


ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          ExpansionPanelList(
                            expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
                              setState(() {
                                isExpandeder = !isExpanded;
                              });
                            },
                            children: [
                              ExpansionPanel(
                                headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                                  return Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Header"),
                                      const Spacer(),
                                      Text("username")
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                                body: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      _signals![index].pair.toString(),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                isExpanded: isExpanded,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: _signals!.length,
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to have a list of bool values to store expanded values since you have only one value maximum. You can store index of currently expanded tile.
2. In your `ListView` you actually create multiple `ExpansionPanelList`s with one element each, instead of one list with all of them. You don't need a `ListView` at all.

You can try the following code in Dartpad, it does what you want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var content = ['text', 'more text', 'another text', 'random text'];
  int? expandedItemIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                if (!isExpanded) {
                  expandedItemIndex = panelIndex;
                } else {
                  expandedItemIndex = null;
                }
              });
            },
            children: [
              for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++)
                ExpansionPanel(
                  headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                    return Text("Header $i");
                  },
                  body: Text(content[i]),
                  isExpanded: expandedItemIndex == i,
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code
There is a problem. When I click on each panel, the first panel opens

Comment: i checked again, copy-pasitng the code from the answer to Dartpad and ran it. it works as expected, opens one that is pressed, closes other if it was open.

Comment: Oh, I wrote part of the code wrong
thank you

Answer (score 0):

> And this is because I use one variable for all of them How can this be
> solved?

You already answered your question. You need a List of booleans or you add a isExpanded boolean in your signals object. If you have only variable, all the ExpansionPanels will behave the same.

You could do something like this:

```
List<bool> isExpanded = [];
for(int i = 0; i < _signals.length; i++){
   isExpanded.add(false);
}
```

So every expanded panel is collapsed at first time.

Now in your ExpansionPanel you just read the bool at position index:

```
 isExpanded: isExpanded[index],
```

And to switch your expansion panel state just invert the bool at the position in the isExpanded list:

```
expansionCallback: (panelIndex, isExpanded) {
                              setState(() {
                                isExpanded[index] = !isExpanded[index];
                              });
                            },
```

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, but still the panels that are open do not close